# Retrofit 2 - how to post image using retrofit of form data

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data, retrofit2, form-data

How to post this body type **form-data** using retrofit. I tried with **@Part** but image is not getting save on server. Any idea where I'm making a mistake?

```
@Multipart
@POST("/saveData")
Call<MyResponse> saveImage(
        @Part("empsno") String empsno,
        @Part("lrSno") String lrsno,
        @Part("deliveryDate") String deliverydate,
        @Part("deliveryTime") String delvrytime,
        @Part("uploadFile") String upldfile,
        @Part("remarks") String remark,
        @Part("receivedBy") String recvdby,
        @Part("place") String place,
        @Part("ipAddress") String ip,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part images
);
```

By using form data I'm successfully able to post data:

[image]

Comment: Did you take a look at this ? https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Comment: yes , tried now but not get successfull

Comment: yeah now got the answer. thanks @Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes **String** to **ResponseBody** and now everything working fine

```
@Multipart
@POST("/saveData")
Call<MyResponse> saveImage(
    @Part("empsno") ResponseBody empsno,
    @Part("lrSno") ResponseBody lrsno,
    @Part("deliveryDate") ResponseBody deliverydate,
    @Part("deliveryTime") ResponseBody delvrytime,
    @Part("uploadFile") ResponseBody upldfile,
    @Part("remarks") ResponseBody remark,
    @Part("receivedBy") ResponseBody recvdby,
    @Part("place") ResponseBody place,
    @Part("ipAddress") ResponseBody ip,
    @Part MultipartBody.Part images
);
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this detailed question? It would be really appreciate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-after-nougat-using-retrofit

Comment: Yeah why not. Give some time, will reply you back